# How to find the best value of K ? (Big-O)

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Can anyone help me with finding out the best value of K in the following assertion as x goes to 0:
$$cos(x)-1+x^2/2=O (x^k)$$

Thanks in advance!

Ali

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.**  As $x \to 0$, by the [Taylor expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Definition), one may prove that
$$
\cos x=1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+O(x^6)
$$ giving

> $$
> \cos x - 1+\frac{x^2}{2}=O(x^4)
> $$

the best value you are looking for is thus $K=4$.

Comment: TNX for your nice answer.

Comment: How about tan^-1(x)= X+O(x^k)

Comment: @ Olivier do you mean that I can solve the next problem with a similar approach?!

Comment: Yes you can. I would like to show it to you. But can you first **accept** my above answer. Thanks!

Comment: I can't find it!!